# Where do my finishers go when stored?

Tags: destiny-2

I mistakenly "stored" my Heihachi style headbutt instead of equipping (as opposed to having my finishers set on random). It's gone as far as I can tell and I can't find it, I can't re-obtain it from my season rewards, it's not in my lost items at the postmaster. I would have to imagine it's somewhere if I "stored" cause it would've otherwise said discard (right?...right!?).

I tried storing my tai chi palm strike too just to pay extra close attention and maybe see where it goes or see if with both finishers stored, something would happen. With no luck, I'm out of options but to come here because searching through google is not helping at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to reacquire them from the flair section of the collections tab. I did the same thing earlier.

Comment: You're a life saver.